# Updating Python module (sympy using easy_install)

Tags: python, module, easy-install

So I have `sympy` version 0.7.3, which I installed using `easy_install` I believe.  I'm now trying to update it to the current version 0.7.6.  My OS is Windows 8 [edit: and I'm using Python 2.7].

When I googled how to update modules in Python I got the impression that I should be able to open the command line and type `easy_install sympy -U` but when I do it seems to check a server and ultimately gives me the error

```
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('-U')
```

I've also tried `easy_install sympy -U` and I get essentially the same error.  Any guidance on what I should be doing?

Comment: try `easy_install --upgrade SomePackage`

Comment: @itzmeontv Nope, same basic error.

Comment: @itzmeontv Ah, I lied, that worked!  I had the order wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `-U` in front of `package name`.

```
easy_install -U SomePackage
```

OR

```
easy_install --upgrade SomePackage
```